# C++ class hierarchy in which to add functionality with an interface

Tags: c++, design-patterns

C++. Imagine the following situation.

There's a class hierarchy of classes deriving from some base class A.
We cannot modify A because it is outside of our scope.
(Provided by a library, it is a MFC CView class, but that shouldn't matter here)

So there are A1, A2 etc which are different classes somehow derived from A and providing specific functionality.

Now imagine we define some new interface I to provide some new functionality.

Classes for concrete objects of the application will inherit from both one of the As and I.
Let's call them Bs. (There are again several of them, like B1 derived from A1 and I, B2 derived from A2 and I etc.)

Now it happens that to implement the interface of I, there is a lot of common code that needs functionality from A.
How can we organize the class hierarchy without repeating ourselves too much.

So for instance if there is a function I::f that needs to call A::f, for all derived classes Bn.
It seems like waste to re-implement I::f for every Bn.
But obviously, we cannot call A::f directly from I::f, as they aren't related.

I hope you get the point.

What is the pattern that can help us here?

Comment: It sounds like you've got the application logic tied up in your View classes;  any shared logic like that should really exist independently of any View classes, consider looking into the Model-View-Presenter pattern to split the logic away from the Views.   Classes which inherit `CView` should only really deal with appearance and layout of their respective UI "widgets" without having any logic in them at all. -- e.g. button-click/event logic or validation or database stuff, etc. doesn't really belong in a 'View' class, and probably doesn't want to be polluted by concerns related to MFC.

Comment: @BenCottrell, you may be right. But for the sake of argument, just ignore the CView information. Or pretend that we implement additional appearance related functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate solution to "call `A::f` from `I::f` without overhauling everything" would be `dynamic_cast`:

```
struct I {
    void f() {
        dynamic_cast<A *>(this)->f();
    }
};
```

Note that this performs a full-fledged RTTI graph traversal to perform the cross-cast through the unknown `Ax` dynamic type of the object, so it might be on the slow side of things.

Comment: Yeah, that's what we have at the moment. But it looks very awkward. An I is not garantueed to be an A after all. And we think about implementing a particular case where we indeed derive from I but NOT from A.

Comment: @Scrontch `dynamic_cast` will behave correctly if you try to cast to a nonexistent subobject: the pointer version will return `nullptr`, which you can check or assert for, the reference version (`dynamic_cast<A &>(*this)`) will throw `std::bad_alloc`.